# Link magento log_url_info table to products

Tags: magento

I want to create a report on the items which are viewed within my store. I have the relevant report writing and SQL skills, but am a little confused by the data within the log_url_info table.

I understand that entries with a value in the url field such as 'http://www.mystore.com/catalog/product/view/id/526' demonstrate a visit to product with ID 526, but cannot see a simple way to link this data back to an individual product record in the relevant product tables, especially given the additional data also stored in this table.

Anyone any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Pull the `id` out of the url, then load the appropriate product.

```
if (preg_match('%/catalog/product/view/id/([0-9]+)%', $url, $match)) {
    $id = $match[1];
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    echo $product->getName(), ', ', $product->getSku(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL scheme in Magento is based on:
`[magento-url]/module/controller/action/arg1/val1/arg2/val2/arg3/val3/.../argn/valn`

If a product is shown to the customer he access `/catalog/product/view/` with the argument `id=[product-id]` (or, in Magento's way of URL handling) `/id/[product-id]`.

Therefore you can parse the URL's in your `log_url_visitor` table or you write a little Magento module which tracks access to the product view page and safe it somewhere.